# Why is my custom Gradle task running even when the input is unchanged

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-task

I've created a custom Gradle task in Java (just put within buildSrc, so a local custom task)

```
public class ImageMergerTask extends DefaultTask{
    public File directory;

    @TaskAction
    public void greet() {
        System.out.println("hello from ImageMergerTask " + directory.toString());
    }

    @InputDirectory
    public File getDirectory(){
        return directory;
    }

    public void setDirectory(File directory){
        this.directory = directory;
    }
}
```

Used in the build.gradle like

```
task imageMerger(type : ImageMergerTask) {
    directory file('src/main/resources/someFolder')
}

processResources.dependsOn(imageMerger);
```

My impression is that by annotating getDirectory() with @InputDirectory, it ought to only run this task if the contents of src/main/resources/someFolder changes, but it seems to run every time, always including in the console:

```
> Task :imageMerger
hello from ImageMergerTask C:\Users\richa\Documents\Development\starlight\src\main\resources\someFolder
```

How should a custom task declare its inputs to properly take advantage of up-to-date detection?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that gradle doesn't make the up-to-date detection unless there is also an output directory. Adding this to the task made it correctly only run the task when the contents of the input directory changed

```
@OutputDirectory
public File getOutDirectory(){
    return new File(getProject().getBuildDir(), "someFolder");
}
```

As found by @ThomasKläger the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks) confirms this

> Also note that incremental build won’t work unless a task has at least one task output

Comment: This matches what the [Gradle doccumentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks) says: _Also note that incremental build won’t work unless a task has at least one task output[, ...]_

Comment: @ThomasKläger Nice! Do you mind if I add that into my answer, or would you like to write your own

Comment: I would suggest that you add it to your answer.